# Can someone explain why the .split method in Ruby works this way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split

Why does .split create an empty character when its argument is the first letter of the string, and it doesn't do the same when the argument is the last letter of the string? In the second example, doesn't it "say", since nothing is on my right I'll output "" ? (Is there a 'nil' at the end of the string?)

I know this is not a very relevant question, however, I'd like to understand why the method behaves this way. Thank you!

```
string = "aware"
string.split("a") --> # outputs: ["", "w", "re"]
string.split("e") --> # outputs: ["awar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple example of behavioral oddity that String#split may seem to have:

```
"1234".split(/1/) # => ["", "234"]
```

It seems like the expected result of the above example would be [“234”] since it is splitting on the 1, but instead we’re getting an unexpected empty string.
**

> How String#split works

**
Internally String#split only uses regular expression delimiters. If you pass in a string delimiter it will be escaped for a regular expression and then turned into a regular expression:

```
1 2 3 4
 "1234".split("1") # is really the same as "1234".split( Regexp.new( Regexp.escape("1") ) )
```

For the remainder of this article when I refer to delimiter I am referring to a regular expression delimiter since internally that is what String#split uses.
String#split keeps track the track of five important pieces of information:

- the string itself

  a results array which is returned

  the position marking where to start matching the string against the
  delimiter. This is the start position and is initialized to 0.

  the position marking where the string matched the delimiter. This is
  the matched position and is initialized to 0.

  the position marking the offset immediately following where the
  string matched the delimiter

String#split operates in a loop. It continues to match the string against the delimiter until there are no more matches that can be found. It performs the following steps on each iteration:

- from the start position match the delimiter against the string
- set the matchedposition to where the delimiter matched the string
- if the delimiter didn’t match the string then break the loop
- create a substring using the start and matched positions of the
  string being matched. Push this substring onto the results array
- set the start position for the next iteration

With this knowledge let’s discuss how String#split handles the previous example of:

```
"1234".split(/1/) # => ["", "234"]
```

- the first loop
- the start position is initialized to 0
- the delimiter is matched against the string “1234”
- the first match occurs with the first character, “1” which is at
  position 0. This sets the matched position to 0.
- a substring is created using the start and matched positions and
  pushed onto our result array. This gives us string[start,end] which
  translates to “1234”[0,0] which returns an empty string.
- the start position is reset to position 1
- The second loop
- start is now 1
- The delimiter is matched against the remainder of our string, “234”
- No match is found so the loop is finished.
- A substring is created using the start position and remainder of the
  string and pushed onto the results array
- the results array is returned

Given how String#split works it is easy to see why we have that unexpected empty string in our results array. You should note that this only occurred because the regular expression matched our string at the first character. Below is an example where the delimiter doesn’t match the first character and there is no empty string:

```
"1234".split(/2/) # => ["1", "34"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer @dheerajsharma ! Explaining it through regular expressions is really helpful.

Comment: Most Welcome @JoanaB

Answer (score 0):

The pickaxe book says of string#split

If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing empty fields are suppressed. ... If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned and trailing null [empty] fields are not suppressed. So:

```
irb(main):001:0> "aware".split('e')
=> ["awar"]
irb(main):002:0> "aware".split('e',-1)
=> ["awar", ""]
```